# Sorting unsigned ints in Go

Tags: sorting, go

I want to sort a slice of `[]uint`. Does this make sense? Is there something I'm missing about `uint`s that make them unsortable? I notice that the [sort package](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/) has an `IntSlice` and `Float64Slice`, but nothing for `uint`.

If `uint`s *are* sortable, then can I just copy the same implementation for `Len()`, `Less(i, j int)` and `Swap(i, j int)` that they've used for the `sort.IntSlice`?

Comment: Why wouldn't they be sortable? The sort package doesn't implement a sort for every possible type,  and unsigned values are typically not used for ordinals, so it's not common to sort them

Comment: I don't know, I guess I was just thinking maybe they weren't comparable in the same way. As you say, they're generally used as nominal values, and there's maybe some weird edge cases, like `var x uint32 = math.MaxUint32; x+1 == 0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for 1.7, you can sort any slice that implements [sort.Interface](https://tip.golang.org/pkg/sort/#Interface) for an alias type of your []uint slice and using [sort.Sort(Interface)](https://tip.golang.org/pkg/sort/#Sort) . In Go 1.8, you will have the option to use [sort.Slice](https://tip.golang.org/pkg/sort/#Slice). See the example [here](https://play.golang.org/p/gCVJwucNQc)

Comment: Ah, that's brilliant, thanks! Really interesting to see the `reflect.Swapper` that's used to do the reflection for the sort. Looking forward to Go 1.8.